# using a simple assert() macro

Tags: c++, assert

I'm new to programming & i found this code when i was going through a book. I believe it gives an example of how to use a defined assert() macro. It doesn't compile on code::blocks 10.05. I get errors such as

1. '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
2. unterminated #else
3. in function 'int main()' 'ASSERT' was not declared in this scope

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#define DEBUG

#ifndef DEBUG  
#define ASSERT(x)
#else
#define ASSERT(x)\   
if(!(x))\
{\
       cout<<"Error!!Assert"<<#x<<"failed\n";\
       cout<<"on line"<<__LINE__<<"\n";\
       cout<<"in file"<<__FILE__<<"\n";\
}\
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    cout<<"\nFirst assert.";
    ASSERT(x==5);
    cout<<"\nSecond assert.";
    ASSERT(x!=5);
    cout<<"\nDone."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you putting an empty line before

    #define ASSERT(x)\
    
    if(!(x))\

? Try taking out the empty line if you are.

Comment: You probably have an empty line after a macro definition line ending with a backslash. You must keep your macro definition lines together, ending each line with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!(x))\
{\
       cout<<"Error!!Assert"<<#x<<"failed\n";\
       cout<<"on line"<<__LINE__<<"\n";\
       cout<<"in file"<<__FILE__<<"\n";\
} // no backslash
```

Comment: Except surely you mean `/*no backslash*/`, in case the Original Poster's code has a line like `ASSERT(x); DoSomethingImportant();`  :-)

Comment: I don't see a problem with the comments. What you would have a problem with is usages like: `if (x) ASSERT(y) else foobar(z);`

Comment: @UncleBens the // would comment out DoSomethingImportant().

Comment: @Jon: Doesn't tokenization (including comment removal) occur before macro expansion?

Comment: @Uncle there is one compiler i know (nvcc) that goes crazy having '//' in macros.  :-(

Comment: @UncleBens: You're right (says http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Phases). Thanks for pointing that out.